# Show files in Broccoli-tree?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

My Ember-CLIs vendor.js is taking up way too much space.
Therefore I'd like to be able to see which files go into its Brocolli-tree.

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-stew but it only shows me the resulting files (including the big vendor.js)